# Where can I ask about the history of video games?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Initially I thought [Arqade (f. Gaming)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) would be the place, but it seems that they've decided to narrow down the scope, and anything that is not *"a real-world problem that you face, requiring a solution"* is off-topic.

Doesn't seem to be match for [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) either, as it isn't really about developing a game.

So is there any SE site that a question about history of video games and gaming would be on-topic?

Example of such a question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11205/which-was-the-first-game-with-bullet-time

Another example as requested by Night Demonbobby, a question I would have asked (actually found [answer on Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/5625054/the-history-of-headshots-gamings-favorite-act-of-unreal-violence) in the mean time):

> Title: *What is the origin of head-shot damage multiplier?*
>
> Which game introduced head-shot damage multiplier and what was the original
>   rationale behind it?

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific? I tend to rely on Wikipedia for the history of *well-known* games like chess or pachinko.

Comment: @Shog9: made subject more specific to *video* games, added an example question.

Comment: The example helps, thanks.

Comment: SE, probably no. Maybe you can try reddit or some gaming forums?

Comment: Also... wow, MDK... forgot about that game.

Comment: @Shog me, too. I had to Google some screenshots to remember which one it was. Now what does that tell us about the game?... It had cool graphics, though.

Answer (score 3):

/r/gaming jumps to mind.

On a more serious note, no, such questions do not belong on the SE network. They're hard to answer for the most part and might yield discussions ("x had it first!" - "But y had a similar effect!" - "z was the best anyway..."). Why are they hard to answer? Well...do you know someone who knows *all* games? So even if you arrive at a consensus ("Okay, y was first.") who can tell you if that is correct?

And if you now have the idea "well, then let's listen all games with that effect." that's even more then off-topic and not constructive (see shopping questions for a relative).

Your example already shows the problem. Despite that the answer looks valid and good, it boils down to "There were *these* games with similar effects.".

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with that rationale. There is one correct answer. Who can tell you which one? The community using upvotes/downvotes. So it's really not a case of a poll question in disguise. Also keep in mind that example is just that, an example.

Comment: @vartec: In that case the example does not fit your questions (or is a poor example for your use-case)...can you add the question you'd like to ask (including title)?

Comment: Ok, updated the question with example

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what [Arqade's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) stance on historical questions was 4 years ago, but historical gaming questions don't seem to be off-topic anymore.

There's even a dedicated [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history) tag for questions like these.

> **About [gaming-history](/questions/tagged/gaming-history)**
>
> Questions about the history of games, conventions, customs, traditions and gaming terms, and how they have developed over time.
>
> #### Tagged Questions
>
> - [Unsold Atari videogames dumped in a desert?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295367/unsold-atari-videogames-dumped-in-a-desert)
> - **[Origin of achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179069/origin-of-achievements)**
> - **[What is the origin of the WASD key scheme?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132715/what-is-the-origin-of-the-wasd-key-scheme)**
> - [What sort of hardware was used to transfer Mew at Pokemon Red & Blue worldwide events?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207978/what-sort-of-hardware-was-used-to-transfer-mew-at-pokemon-red-blue-worldwide-e)
> - **[How did the term 'buff' originate?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178294/how-did-the-term-buff-originate)**