# Allow cross-site tag linking

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown

**I would like an option on Meta communities to reference tags from different sites, similar to the distinction between `[tag:]` and `[meta-tag:]`.**

To keep things standardized, cross-site tags could use the same naming-format as [data.SE styled "magic links"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments).

- `[so-tag:java]` → [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- `[su-tag:microsoft-excel]` → [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)
- `[gaming-tag:gaming-history]` → [gaming-history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gaming-history)

---

Questions where cross-site tags would be helpful

- [What symbols/characters are not allowed in tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298981/351462)
- [Is there an SE site where I can ask about the history of video games?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299477/351462)
- [Where should I ask a question about NFS Most Wanted (2005)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299476/351462)